# Element type is invalid. Expected a string, found undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

This one occurred just after a `next-auth` update. Suddenly it throws this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MyApp`.
```

So I checked the MyApp file, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong about it, nothing that I have seen at least.

**_app.tsx** (_app file in next.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { start, done } from "nprogress";
import "nprogress/nprogress.css";
import router from "next/router";
import "./styles/patch.css";
import { Provider } from "next-auth/client";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { useApollo } from "../apollo/apolloClient";

router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => start());
router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => done());
router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => done());

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const apolloClient = useApollo(pageProps.initialApolloState);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

Did I miss something that could've caused this error?

**EDIT:**

Apparently, it was fine when I used webpack 4. It threw this error upon using webpack 5. But it would be good if there was a solution for webpack 5.

**EDIT 2:**

When I updated `next` to version `10.2`, it worked perfectly fine. I must've been hasty on things perhaps so I guess there wasn't any problem in the first place. Other than that, I appreciate the answers that had been put in here.

Comment: One thing that'll cause that error is `Component` being `undefined`.

Comment: ```Component``` is a function parameter. This is an _app file in nextjs.

Answer (score 0):

do not use query like this :

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
     // this is wrong !!! 
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, [])
```

try using useRef hook instead ex:

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this file was actually the _app file in nextjs, exported as MyApp (no issue with that). Basically what this means is that it's global, and whatever ```"#jss-server-side"``` is is actually getting reached, and I could say for sure that that part works perfectly fine before the ```next-auth``` update.